# Detect which circuit has current

Tags: current

I am trying to build a kind of frame where I have laser diodes on one side and LDRs on the other, and current flows through the LDR circuit if the light from the laser opposite to it is blocked. Basically kind of an IR touchscreen frame, but with lasers. The power supply is just a 5v power supply with a 10k resistor and a 5k-20M LDR. Here is the schematic for the detector circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT7BRF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have 10 identical circuits corresponding to 10 lasers on the other side, and current will be flowing through only one of them at a time based on which one is blocked. I want to figure out a way to detect which circuit the current is flowing through. Maybe like a number between 1 to 10 sent to a Rpi. My initial thought was that I could make a junction at the same point in each circuit (somewhere on before the collector perhaps) and connect resistors of different values to that, and then the other end of all of those resistors could go into an INA219, which could then go back to the original circuits. So basically a bunch of wires going into and out of the INA219 but the current flowing through only one of them. Then I could read the current value received by the current sensor and based on the value I would know which circuit it was because of the different values of resistances. But this seems very inefficient and doesn't sound like a good idea for more than 10 circuits together (or a good idea at all). I wonder if there is a better way to do this (using ICs or something).

I am very very new to electronics, just trying to pick it up as a hobby, so I apologise if my question is extremely stupid. I have been trying to find resources but considering that this is an entire profession, it is a bit hard to look for information that I can understand easily. I don't even know what tags go best here, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome :-) I recommend you edit the question and add more context / background e.g. what are these 10 identical circuits? What voltage / current / frequency are involved? Why do you want to detect something about them being used - what is the project? Why did you decide to detect current flow, rather than the presence of a voltage? Giving us more information about the *real* problem you want to solve, will reduce the risk of an XY-Problem situation, where current detection might turn out *not* to be the best solution to the real problem, even though that is what you asked about! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will edit it right away based on your suggestions. I actually don't know if current detection is the best idea at all, so yeah letting the pros help with that is a better idea lol. Thanks!

Comment: To what extent is your implementation fixed, are you using specific hardware you can't change or can it be adapted to help with the above scenario? Could you provide a signal into a gpio input from the active circuit to identify it as active.

Comment: @mhaselup not much is fixed since I am just playing around with stuff. I edited the question to give a bit more context. I just have a bunch of light blocking detection circuits basically and I just want to figure out which one of the circuits is detecting a block. Since I might want to have a lot of these circuits, I don't know if I can just send signals to separate gpio inputs for all of them

Comment: Could you use a multiplexing solution and "scan" the LDR detectors e.g. along the lines of https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/41869/using-capacitive-sensing-library-with-a-74hc4067-multiplexer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at a multiplexing solution where you could "scan" the detector circuits. Something along the lines of https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/41869/using-capacitive-sensing-library-with-a-74hc4067-multiplexer. This approach could allow 16 detectors to be monitored from a single GPIO pin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will look into that.